# Stereographic Projection and Charts

Tags: analysis, manifolds

This question was asked in online assignment of my manifolds course and I was not able to solve this particular question.

> Question :  Let NP and SP $ \in S^2$ denote the  north and south pole of the unit sphere $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ . Denote by $\pi_{NP}$ stereographic projection of $S^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the north pole : $\pi_{NP}$ :$S^2 /${NP} $\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and denote by $\psi_{NP} $ its inverse.

(a) Determine the explicit expression for $\phi_{NP}$ and $\psi_{NP}$ and show that $\psi_{NP} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to S^2 $ is a local chart.

(b) Determine the change of charts/ co-ordinates of $\psi^{-1}_{NP}\circ \psi_{SP}$ and $\psi^{-1}_{SP} \circ \psi_{NP}$ as well as their domain of definition.

Attempt: I was not able to determine the expression of $\phi_{NP}$ or the expression of $\psi_{NP}$ and so I am not able to proceed from this. Till the point these expressions are not deduced, the answer will not move foreward. So, kindly let me know a proof of the expressions of $\phi_{NP}$ and $\psi_{NP}$.

Rest of the verification of charts I will like to do it by myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint for the stereographic projection from the north pole: determine the equation of the line passing through $NP=(0,0,1)$ and $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S^2\setminus \{NP\}$ (recall that in $\Bbb R^3$, by two distinct points pass a unique affine line). Now, the stereographic projection of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the equatorial plane is the unique point $(x,y,z)$ on that line with altitude $z=0$.
From this, you should be able to determine $\phi_{NP}$.

Comment: And as some say, [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddvig.png) is worth a thousand words